# How can i add a file to an importXml method?

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk

i am trying to import an xml in actionscript. I a mworking with the indesgin SDK.

Now the SDK is telling me the following:

> importXML(fromParam:File = null):void Imports the specified XML file
>   into an InDesign document.

And a the moment i'm doing it this way:

```
document.importXML(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("baseXml.xml"));
```

But the problem is that i cant ask the user to add an xml file to their desktop so i can import it when needed. So i added the xml to my project. I added it to the package:

```
resources/xml/baseXml.xml
```

Now my problem is that i cant seem to be able to my `File` object to this path and thus cant select the xml file. Can anyone help me solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML file isn't in your desktop directory, it's in the application folder. Try:

```
document.importXML(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("resources/xml/baseXml.xml"));
```

The files in the application directory are read-only, however, so if you plan on modifying the XML file you can copy it to somewhere in the `applicationStorageDirectory` using `copyTo`.

The other option is to allow the user to choose the file path by using `file.browseForOpen`.